# What changes were made to the CLR to support dynamic?

Tags: .net, cil, dynamic-language-runtime

As I understand it, the .net 4.0 CLR needed to make changes to support the Dynamic Language Runtime.

Is there a way to see what those changes were? I noticed that the .net standard does not mention things like DynamicObject - all these things seem to be part of the DLR. But if the DLR is "just a library", then there would be no need for .net 4 to run it.

So I'm just curious what changed in .net 4 to support the DLR.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the CLR changed? It changed, but not to support DLR.

Comment: @Gabe Good point. It just came up here and there, but people tend to mix C#4 and .net 4 together. See for example here: http://eknowledger.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!F475D4DE444DB1AB!3407.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=209990974 where it vaguely says that CLR neeed changes to support dynamic languages, but then only shows library changes (e.g. System.Tuple), so I wonder what the full extent here is or if the DLR is 100% library code.

Comment: The big CLR change is variance support, and the DLR may make use of that.

Comment: @Gabe: The CLR has supported generic variance since 2.0, but none of the languages (aside from MSIL) did until 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No changes, it is just a library.  The .NET 4.0 CLR wasn't needed, the DLR powered IronPython and IronRuby on the 2.0 version.  You can have a look-see at what makes it tick from that version, you can download the source code [from here](http://dlr.codeplex.com/).  This code was moved into System.Core.dll largely unchanged.

Beware that there's rather a lot of it.  It is all straight C#.  It uses existing support in the CLR for dynamic binding through Reflection and COM interop.  Its claim to fame is that it can do so by paying for that cost only once.  It caches the results of a bind so that it is available at low cost in subsequent binds.

Adding the DLR interface glue to C# version 4 was a considerable effort in itself, embedded in Microsoft.CSharp.dll with lots of work in the compiler.  That source code isn't available but you can sniff it with Reflector.